# Hibernate Exception: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a entity class MailingList and source code are below:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = AccountConstants.TABLE_NAME_MAILING_LIST, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "list_name" }))
@EntityListeners(MailingListListener.class)
public class MailingList extends AbstractBaseEntity implements Serializable, BasicEntity<Long> {
    public static final String MAILINGLIST_PROP_NAME = "list_name";
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mail_list_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mail_list_generator", sequenceName = "mail_list_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "list_name", length = 50, nullable = false, updatable = true) 
    private String name;
}
```

You can see, entity above add listener to class MailingListListener and source code of MailingListListener are below

```
@Component
public class MailingListListener {
    @PrePersist
    public void onPrePersist(Object o) {

        try {
            if (o instanceof Timestampable) {
                Timestampable tso = (Timestampable) o;
                tso.setCreatedAt(new Date());
                tso.setActive(true);
                tso.setCreatedBy(getUserId());
             }
          } catch (Exception e) {
             LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
          }
     }

private void sendMailingList(MailingList mailingList) {

    try {
        MailingListVM vm = MailingListMapper.INSTANCE.toMailingListVM(mailingList);
        KafkaMessage kafkaMsg = KafkaUtil.saveKafkaMessage(vm, BaseConstants.TABLE_NAME_MAILING_LIST, "uaa");

        Map<String, Object> sendingData = new HashMap<>();
        if (mailingList.getActive() == null || mailingList.getActive() == false) {
            sendingData.put(BaseConstants.KAFKA_ACTION, BaseConstants.KAFKA_ACTION_DELETE);
        } else {
            sendingData.put(BaseConstants.KAFKA_ACTION, BaseConstants.KAFKA_ACTION_UPDATE);
        }

        sendingData.put(BaseConstants.TABLE_NAME, BaseConstants.TABLE_NAME_MAILING_LIST + "");

        sendingData.put(MailingList.PROP_ID, mailingList.getId().longValue() + "");
        sendingData.put(MailingList.MAILINGLIST_PROP_NAME, mailingList.getName());
        sendingData.put(MailingList.PROP_CREATED_AT, mailingList.getCreatedAt());
        sendingData.put(MailingList.PROP_UPDATED_AT, mailingList.getUpdatedAt());

        sendingData.put(KafkaMessage.SOURCE_SERVICE, KafkaMessage.UAA_SERVICE);
        sendingData.put(KafkaMessage.KAFKA_MESSAGE_ID, kafkaMsg.getId() != null ? kafkaMsg.getId() + "" : "-1");

        UpdatedUaaPublicProducerChannel updatedUaaPublicProducerChannel = ApplicationContextHolder
                .getBean(UpdatedUaaPublicProducerChannel.class);
        updatedUaaPublicProducerChannel.updateUaaPublic().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(sendingData).build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

    @PostPersist
    public void onPostPersist(Object o) {

        MailingList obj = (MailingList) o;
        send1MailingList(obj);
    }

}
```

You can see code. Whenever I update or insert new record into MailingList table then it will execute function `sendMailingList`. This function just save one record into table `kafka_message` table and send one message to kafka server only. But i could not understand if I comment 2 first line codes of this function then i can run as well

```
MailingListVM vm = MailingListMapper.INSTANCE.toMailingListVM(mailingList);

KafkaMessage kafkaMsg = KafkaUtil.saveKafkaMessage(vm, BaseConstants.TABLE_NAME_MAILING_LIST, "uaa");
```

Content of function `KafkaUtil.saveKafkaMessage` like below

```
public final static KafkaMessage saveKafkaMessage(Object dept, String tableName, String source) {
    Session session = null;
    session = ApplicationContextHolder.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try {
        KafkaMessage kafkaMessage = new KafkaMessage();
        kafkaMessage.setContents(KafkaUtil.writeValueAsString(dept));
        kafkaMessage.setTableName(tableName);
        if(source.equals("device")) {
            kafkaMessage.setDeviceServiceReceived(new Long(2));
        } else if(source.equals("facility")) {
            kafkaMessage.setFacilityServiceReceived(new Long(2));
        } else if(source.equals("archive")) {
            kafkaMessage.setArchiveServiceReceived(new Long(2));
        } else if(source.equals("uaa")) {
            kafkaMessage.setUaaServiceReceived(new Long(2));
        } else if(source.equals("monitoring")) {
            kafkaMessage.setMonitoringServiceReceived(new Long(2));
        } else if(source.equals("sale")) {
            kafkaMessage.setSaleServiceReceived(new Long(2));
        }
        session = ApplicationContextHolder.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                    Transaction transaction = null;
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        session.save(kafkaMessage);
        transaction.commit();
        return kafkaMessage;
    } finally {
        //It will close session to avoid exception that it cannot get connection from pool
        if(session != null)
            session.close();
    }
}
```

Please help me, if you know solution. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace? We cannot help you without knowing what the problem is

Comment: @SimonMartinelli 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664)

Comment: 1) please add it to the question and 2) this is not the whole stacktrace